# Leaflet add layer by user input

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I'm filtering a geojson layer by user inputs,and works fine for the first query, and works fine for the first query, the problem is with the second so on. starting from the second query brings me the last layer plus the new one I already tried map.removeLayer(layer) any ideas on how can I get only the new filter?,

```
function query(data) {
    var input=null;
    var user = null;
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

    departamentos.then(function(data) {
    var alldeptos = L.geoJson(data);  

    user = L.geoJson(data, {

        filter: function (feature, layer) {
            //console.log(feature)
            return feature.properties.nom_dpto == input;
        },

    });
    });
    $("#allbus").click(function() {
        map.addLayer(alldeptos)
        map.removeLayer(user)
    });
    $("#form").click(function() {
        map.removeLayer(alldeptos)
        map.removeLayer(user)
        map.addLayer(user)
    });
   });      
}
```

[image: First filter]

[image: New filter (shouldn't have the first one]

Comment: Proper code indentation is half of a good programming.

Comment: It's  not clear what you would like to achieve. Have displayed only one layer at a time? Clicking `#all` for layer `alldepots`, clicking `#form` for layer `caldas` and clicking `#boyaca` for layer `boyaca`?

Comment: the idea is that the user can  search for an specific __properties.nom_dpto__ and it works fine for the first time, but the second time it brings the new result and also the first one

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not clear. Edit the question and precisely describe just what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hope this time the question is more clear

Comment: Sorry, but I give up.

Comment: thank you!! sooner or later I'll fix this, and I'll post the answer

Comment: I already manage to solve the problem, all I had to do was create a layerGroup, and add line codes you told me @TomazicM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the layer to a new layer group

```
var fil_dpt = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

function query(data) {
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    departamentos.then(function(data) {
    var alldeptos = L.geoJson(data); 
    user = L.geoJson(data, {
        filter: function (feature, layer) {
            //console.log(feature)
            return feature.properties.nom_dpto == input;
        },
    });
    $("#allbus").click(function() {
        if (map.hasLayer(user)) map.removeLayer(user)
        //if (!map.hasLayer(alldeptos)) map.addLayer(alldeptos);
        if (map.hasLayer(alldeptos)){ map.removeLayer(alldeptos)}
            else {map.addLayer(alldeptos)}
});
    $("#form").click(function() {
        fil_dpt.clearLayers();
        if (map.hasLayer(alldeptos)) map.removeLayer(alldeptos);
        //if (!fil_dpt.hasLayer(user)) fil_dpt.addLayer(user);
        if (fil_dpt.hasLayer(user)){ fil_dpt.removeLayer(user)}
             else {fil_dpt.addLayer(user)}
    });
});     
}
```

it was also with the help of deleted answer of @TomazicM
[image: first filter]
[image: second filter]